# data-label not displaying with {grid_field:table}

Tags: grid, table

data-label="{table:column_name}" and scope="col" disappears when loaded into template.

```
{table:table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">{table:column_name}</th>
      <th scope="col">{table:column_name}</th>
      <th scope="col">{table:column_name}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="{table:column_name}">{table:grid_field_1}</td>
      <td data-label="{table:column_name}">{table:grid_field_2}</td>
      <td data-label="{table:column_name}">{table:grid_field_3}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{/table:table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grid field's `:table` modifier is actually just a single tag, not a tag pair.

```
{table:table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="my-table"}
```

That variable by itself will output the entire table including all variables; it's just a shortcut for those who don't want to customize or write their own table markup. See [the `:table` modifer docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/grid.html#table) for details.

You should be able to build your table with whatever markup you need using the regular Grid variable pair, however. E.g.:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Foo</th>
            <th scope="col">Bar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    {table}
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Foo">{table:foo}</td>
          <td data-label="Bar">{table:bar}</td>
        </tr>
    {/table}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect, worked out great! Thanks again Derek.